# Showing a modal dialog during Render/Paint-Event causes UI-Artifacts

Tags: java, swing, user-interface, modal-dialog

As in the title:
Sometimes I have UI artifacts in my swing application, when a modal dialog is/was displayed.

Following situation:

`JTable -> getCellRendererComponent(...)`

```
//This (simplified) method is called by JTable, to get a cell renderer.
private Component getCellRendererComponent(JTable srcTable, int row, int col, ...)
{
   MyService svc = new MyService();
   svc.doServiceCall(); // this causes a Modal-(Please wait/Progress)-Dialog to appear, until the call is finished!
   ...
   ...
   return component;
}
```

When `getCellRendererComponent(...)` is called, it may be possible that also a service-call is made inside this method.
When this service-call uses a modal-(please wait/progress)-dialog, UI-Artifacts are going to appear very often (the UI is not drawn correctly, missing/not drawn parts).
When the service-call is configured to **not show an progress-dialog** (just wait/block Event-Dispatch-Thread), no UI-Artifacts appear (the UI is drawn **correctly**).

**I assume following problem:**
`getCellRendererComponent()` is called when some parts of the table should be re-painted.
That means, a repaint-event (in my application) can cause a service call (which shows a temporary modal dialog).
But when showing a modal-dialog, some ui-events are still processed (e.g `re-paint()` -> which can cause another service-call).

I think it has something to do with Swing and Thread-Safety. (I know, swing is not thread-safe.)

**Question:**

What could be the exact reason and how can I identify/detect this situation (so i can configure the service to not show an progress-dialog)?

**EDIT:**

First, thanks to all responses.
I understand all the complaints by doing this, but the problem is that the application is really big with few developers. I just can't easy avoiding it.

Please don't stick on the service-call-stuff!
(of course, you shouldn't call a WebService in paint-event!!)

The boiled down problem is, that `getCellRendererComponent()` is also used to get the Tables-CellRenderer-Component for another purposes in another places. So it is **not obvious**, that this calls origin is from paint-event.
Further it is not always obvious, that an simple method-call (e.g `getCurrentTime()`) **may** call a webservice (which leads to a modal dialog).

**simplified Example:**

`getCellRendererComponent()` is calling `getCurrentUser()`.
But `getCurrentUser()` is **overridden** in some other place so, `getCurrentUser()` will now also call `getCurrentTime()` (which is calling a service method).
That means, `getCellRendererComponent()` is not directly calling a WebService.

Maybe there is no other option than to check the stacktrace (to get the origin).

Comment: The exact reason is many and varied, needless to say, you should avoid making "secondary" calls from a renderer like this (and from within paint methods), instead, having the data that it needs on hand or allowing the service, when it's completed to update the cells that might need that data

Comment: In general you are totally right, but the problem is a little more complex, since my `getCellRenderComponent()`-Method is called in another places. That means, it is not always clear/obvious that the origin is from repaint/renderer-Event or not.

Comment: Why's it called in other places? May be you need to redesign that problem so it's no

Comment: When getCellRendererComponent(...) is called, it may be possible that also a service-call is made inside this method.  == XxxRenderer is called from all mouse, key events over the JTables view, plus methods implemented in APIs, are you sure that event can be called a few times per one second....

Comment: Renderer is designed to paint JTables view only, nothing else, everything moreover is breaking (better is say to killing) this concept with the mess :-)

Comment: I added an Update...